# Importing CSV with XY coordinates as grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import, vector-grid

In QGIS I am trying to create a grid. I've used the MMQGIS geometry import function to import data from the CSV file shown below but they pop up as points on QGIS.

[image: csv]

I want to make it into a grid so that I can pretty much have each of the points be in a box format. I've also tried to use the join function but am not sure what variable both the grid and the points have so that I can join them.

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS3 you can create a layer from a delimited text file using
[Layer] > [Data Source Manager] > [Delimited Text]
 which allows you to select the delimiter (CVS is one of the options) and to select 2 of the fields (columns) to be used as the X and Y position of the point.  The other fields are stored in the Attribute Table.

Comment: I'm sorry I may not have been clear. I am able to plot the data as points, however I am trying to make a grid with squares in which the data can be displayed. I am trying to go from something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoFS.png to something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HJYSJOrrvIE/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: My apologies - it was my careless reading that was at fault.

Comment: After looking at your from/to example, I think [ Vector > Research Tools > Create grid ] is what you want. Based on your intended CRS, figure out what cell dimensions you want in the CRS units (e.g., meters), how many you want, and the resulting X and Y extents of the entire grid.  Then use Create grid to create a Rectangle (polygon) shape file.  The result is an array of independent rectangles which you can select individually.  They are numbered (ID) starting at the upper left, by columns first.  Other fields are the X,Y locations.  You can add your own fields for data...

Answer (score 1):

you could to interpolate using "TIN Interpolation"

[image]

- Vector Layer: point layer
- Interpolation attribute: field that contain
  data to interpolation
- Interpolation lineal
- Number of columns: number of horizontal points
- Number of rows: number of vertical points

Comment: I'm sorry I may not have been clear. I am able to plot the data as points, however I am trying to make a grid with squares in which the data can be displayed. I am trying to go from something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoFS.png to something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HJYSJOrrvIE/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Yes, I' understood. When you interpolate (TIN Interpolation) you obtain a grid (raster), or do you need vector layer (poligon)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what type of grid you are trying to create exacly (like raster or an array of vector polygons) but this might be what you want: Vector->Research Tools-> Create grid.[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I may not have been clear. I am able to plot the data as points, however I am trying to make a grid with squares in which the data can be displayed. I am trying to go from something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoFS.png to something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HJYSJOrrvIE/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To create some sort of polygon grid from those points, you can:

- first, use the `Points to Path` algorithm (*you can find in Processing*); in the `Group field` and `Order field` be sure to use an attribute which is unique for each of the four corners (*maybe `DEGSQ` from your screenshot*).
- Use the `Lines to polygon` algorithm to obtain the desired polygons.

You can see each of the three geometry phases below:

[image]