# Create a grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, vector-grid

I have GIS points (x, y data) for every minute over a landscape. If I load them up as a CSV into QGIS they all show up as points, which you would expect. However, what I would like to do is use these points to create a grid. In other words, each point is a corner of a 1x1 minute grid. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/287119/49538

Comment: Yes, thanks, that seems to answer my question. But, I don't have the Vector option at all. It goes from Plugins straight to Raster. Any ideas why?